# Tailwind conditional font size not loading

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

My custom conditional Tailwind fonts are being added to the output HTML, but don't do anything.

Component:

```
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

type TextProps = {
  variant?: 'h1' | 'h2' | 'body' | 'label' | 'code';
  children: ReactNode | string;
  className?: string;
} & Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements['span'], 'className'>;

const Text = ({
  variant = 'body',
  children,
  className,
  ...rest
}: TextProps) => {
  return (
    <span
      className={`text-${variant} text-secondary-white font-fira ${
        className ?? ''
      }`}
      {...rest}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  );
};

export default Text;
```

Tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily:{
        fira:['Fira Code']
      },
      colors:{
        primary:{
          black: '#01080E',
          darker: '#011221',
          dark:'#011627',
          medium:'#1C2B3A'
        },
        secondary:{
          main: '#607B96',
          mint:'#3C9D93',
          purple:'#4D5BCE',
          white:'#FFFFFF',
        },
        accent:{
          orange:'#FEA55F',
          mint:'#43D9AD',
          pink:'#E99287',
          purple:'#C988DF'
        },
        gradient:{
          purple:'#4D5BCE',
          mint:'#43D9AD'
        },
        active:{
          orange:"#FFAC6B",
          main:"#263B50",
        },
        line:'#1E2D3d',
      },
      fontSize:{
        h1:'62px',
        h2:'32px',
        body:'18px',
        label:'16px',
        code:'14px'
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

This does compile the classes correctly and if I put in `text-h1` or `text-code` directly it seems to work. So I think it's the string interpolation happens after tailwind creates the classes, but I don't know how to fix it. (Removing `mode:'jit'` doesn't help)

```
<div class="flex flex-col p-20">
  <span class="text-code text-secondary-white font-bla ">Hello world! I am</span>
  <span class="text-h1 text-secondary-white font-bla ">Name_Surname
  </span><span class="text-h2 text-secondary-white font-bla text-secondary-purple">&gt; Full-stack developer</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tailwind is preprocessed before loading to the browser and only used classes are bundled to the final style file.

In your setup, tailwind can't recognize used classes so ignores them.
If you want this to work, you have to store entire classnames in `variants`.

Comment: I'm reading up on variants and they don't seem to be meant for this? Can you give an example of how to move this to variants? Also is there really no way to tell tailwind in the config to preprocess themes like `text-code`?

Comment: `variant?: 'text-h1' | 'text-h2' | 'text-body' | 'text-label' | 'text-code';` for example. I don't believe that there is any other way to do this.

Comment: That doesn't work. Although I did find a cheeky workaround, just add an invisible html tag with all of the classes so that tailwind builds them.

Comment: If you are going to hardcode the classes, you can instead add them to a safelist in your `tailwind.config.js`. See: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, here's how I overcame this issue without any hard coding or external libraries using taiwlind plugins and theme:

```js
// ./tailwind/pluginSafelist.js
const plugin = require("tailwindcss/plugin")
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const pluginSafelist = (outputFile = "./tailwind/safelist.txt") =>
  plugin(({ theme }) => {
    const outputPath = path.join(__dirname, "..", outputFile)
    fs.writeFileSync(outputPath, "")
    const sizes = Object.keys(theme("fontSize"))
    const weights = Object.keys(theme("fontWeight"))
    sizes.forEach((size) => fs.appendFileSync(outputPath, `text-${size}\n`))
    weights.forEach((weight) =>
      fs.appendFileSync(outputPath, `font-${weight}\n`)
    )
  })

module.exports = pluginSafelist
```

```js
// tailwind.config.js
const pluginSafelist = require('./tailwind/pluginSafelist');

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    /* content */
    "./tailwind/safelist.txt" // it must point to the output txt file
  ],
  theme: {
    fontWeight: {
      regular: "400",
      medium: "500",
      bold: "700"
    },
    fontSize: {
      xs: ["0.75rem", { lineHeight: "0.875rem" }],
      sm: ["0.875rem", { lineHeight: "1.0625rem" }],
      base: ["1rem", { lineHeight: "1.1875rem" }],
      lg: ["1.125rem", { lineHeight: "1.375rem" }],
      xl: ["1.5rem", { lineHeight: "1.8125rem" }],
      "2xl": ["2.25rem", { lineHeight: "2.6875rem" }],
      "3xl": ["3rem", { lineHeight: "3.625rem" }],
      "4xl": ["4rem", { lineHeight: "4.8125rem" }]
    },
  },
  plugins: [pluginSafelist(/*optional path*/)]
}
```

And here's the content of txt file

```
text-xs
text-sm
text-base
text-lg
text-xl
text-2xl
text-3xl
text-4xl
font-regular
font-medium
font-bold
```